# Sort SortedSet by item member

Tags: c#, .net, collections, set

Consider this class

```
public class A
{
     float Order
     string Name
     public A(float order, string name)
     {
           Order = order;
           Name = name;
     }
}
```

If I were to add this to a `SortedSet<A>` how would it know which member to order it by? How would I specify this, if I even can in the first place. I imagine that the best performance of the set would be sorting it on add, not adding then sorting through `Sort()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SortedSet<A>` will expect your class to implement `IComparable<A>`. Alternatively, you can supply a comparator of type [`IComparer<A>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the ordering externally to your class, like this:

```
class ComparerForClassAByOrder : IComparer<A> {
    public int Compare(A left, A right) {
        return Math.Sign(left.Order-right.Order);
    }
}

class ComparerForClassAByName : IComparer<A> {
    public int Compare(A left, A right) {
        return left.Name.CompareTo(right.Name);
    }
}
```

Now you can create two sorted sets using different comparators:

```
var soredByOrder = new SortedSet<A>(new ComparerForAByOrder());
var soredByName = new SortedSet<A>(new ComparerForAByName());
```

Comment: Ok, new issue, let's say I wish to create two SortedSets, one orders by `Order`, the other by `Name`, I'm guessing this would not be possible since you can only inherit `IComparable`once :(

Comment: @redcodefinal, in this case implement several specific IComparer<A> types (for each desired order you wish).

Comment: @elgonzo thanks, be sure to look it up! thanks for the help dasblinkenlights.

Comment: @redcodefinal, let your class A implement IComparable<A> with the default natural ordering of A (if there is such a natural order for your class). For other order schemes, implement specific IComparer<A> types.

Comment: There is a static method `Comparer<A>.Create` which creates a comparer for you from a "formula" (delegate); see my answer.

Comment: @Jeppe, yes, Comparer<T> has the advantage that you can use lambda expressions (as demonstrated by your answer).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you change the accessibility so that you can *read* the members of `A` from outside the class, you can simply do:

```
new SortedSet<A>(Comparer<A>.Create((a1, a2) => a1.Order.CompareTo(a2.Order)))
```

This requires .NET 4.5 or later.

Remember that `NaN` will compare less than everything else.

If you do not pass in your own comparer to the constructor, it will be checked if each instance of `A` is of a run-time type which implements `IComparable<>` or `IComparable`. If not, an error is produced when adding to the `SortedSet<A>`.